# Mac OS High Sierra: Access denied while test connection in MySql WorkBench v8.0.13 Community

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySql Workbench 8.0.13, I'm trying to test localhost connection.

[image]

I tried root, admin, root@123, YES, none of the passwords work and instead shows error messages.

[image]

I've even tried other stackoverflow answers but instead got "access denied" error messages.

### Update

After @Yoric answer: **brew install mysql**

I tried configuring the local management settings but I'm getting this:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to enter in the terminal: `mysql -u root` ?

Comment: @Yoric: Getting this -> -bash: mysql: command not found

Comment: Mysql Workbench won't install Mysql so you need to install it on your own before to use it. I advise you to install `brew` for Mac, then just enter into the terminal `brew install mysql`

Comment: have you tried to login with cmd?

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal What does the command `mysql --verbose --help | grep my.cnf` return to you from the terminal? Check from the first path to the last if you have a `my.cnf` file there.

Comment: @Yoric: THiS

Last login: Fri Dec 28 17:45:44 on ttys002
Abhisheks-MacBook-Pro:~ abhishekthapliyal$ mysql --verbose --help | grep my.cnf
                      order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
Abhisheks-MacBook-Pro:~ abhishekthapliyal$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install MySql using brew the my.cnf file is placed in `/usr/local/etc/` instead of in `/etc/`.
You have to point MySQl Workbench to this path to avoid the error. I don't have this application but after a quick glance in the documentation I found [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-system-profile.html) where you can add `/usr/local/etc/` in the field `Configuration File`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Yoric @Joakim

Step 1. `brew install mysql`

Step 2: Refer this answer to locate config file

> I met this problem too. I just clicked the continue button until i was
>   at "Review remote management settings" step, and stop here click
>   "change parameters", then continue. At "Path to configuration file"
>   choose the path point to my-default.cnf. Then check path, it works

**REF**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24028563/5589073

Step 3. @Joakim told about the correct path, i updated in step 2 path while change parameters. It works.

Thanks all 3 guys.